# vim-mode-plus keymaps for switching between panes not working

Tags: atom-editor

I have installed **vim-mode-plus** package and added the following keymap bindings in the **keymap.cson** file.

```
 'atom-text-editor.vim-mode-plus.normal-mode':
   'ctrl-j': 'focus-pane-or-panel:focus-below'
   'ctrl-k': 'focus-pane-or-panel:focus-above'
   'ctrl-h': 'focus-pane-or-panel:focus-on-left'
```

however I am not able to switch between the panes ( I am on Windows)

I am able to switch if I use a built-in keybinding as below:

```
ctrl-w ctrl-j   window:focus-pane-below Vim Mode Plus   atom-text-editor.vim-mode-plus:not(.insert-mode)
```

Above is copied from the **Keybindings** search results in atom

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you are using the right command names. If you open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>), you can search "focus" and find the various commands available for what you're trying to do.

- Window: Focus Pane Above
- Window: Focus Pane Below
- Window: Focus Pane On Left
- Window: Focus Pane On Right

To turn these into keybind command names, apply this formula:

1. Lowercase everything
2. Remove the space after `:`
3. Replace remaining spaces with hyphens

This gives the keybind command names:

- `window:focus-pane-above`
- `window:focus-pane-below`
- `window:focus-pane-on-left`
- `window:focus-pane-on-right`

Also notice the working example you point to uses a different selector than you are using. It uses `atom-text-editor.vim-mode-plus:not(.insert-mode)` rather than `atom-text-editor.vim-mode-plus.normal-mode`. That may be a better option, so your key bindings would work in modes other than normal mode (such as visual select mode).

I think what you need is:

```coffeescript
'atom-text-editor.vim-mode-plus:not(.insert-mode)':
   'ctrl-j': 'window:focus-pane-below'
   'ctrl-k': 'window:focus-pane-above'
   'ctrl-h': 'window:focus-pane-on-left'
```

And I'm not sure if you also wanted <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to work, e.g.

```coffeescript
'ctrl-l': 'window:focus-pane-on-right'
```